# How to undelete just deleted directory with "rm -R" command?

Tags: centos6, undelete, virtualization

I deleted an important directory with `rm -R` command.
This is an very populer host data. It was located `/var/zpanel/hostdata/ayrintilih`
After remove ayrintilih directory has gone everything.

I tried to undelete with `ext4magic` program. But it need to another hdd volume for recovery.

Error message:

```
ERROR: can not use "/root/recoveried" for recover directory. It's the same filesystem : "/dev/dm-0"
```

My ISP just replied my request:

```
Unfortunately there is no way to add another Volume to a virtual Instance. 
If it would be a dedicated Server, we could do it, but not in a Cloudserver. 
You could try to minimize the partition and create another one, that would 
count as another Volume. We also recommend to have allways a 
Backup for your Important files.
```

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: As @SvW says, if it is so important you sure have a backup of it, right? Otherwise, restore to another volume? I don't know if a ramdisc would do it, but if it works that could be the way to go.

Comment: Backup file is so old.

Comment: I have only one volume. I leave a message from my isp. Thousends files has gone. `I felt tired and didn't touch anythink like that`

Comment: I think using terminal is very dangerous.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to close this question and ask it over on unix.stackexchange.com.  If possible, stopping any use of that volume as well could help make sure the data is recoverable.  Hope it works out for you.  Also: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `I think using terminal is very dangerous` <-- No, *being careless with what you type* is very dangerous. You are now learning two important lessons: (1) be careful what you type, especially when operating as root. (2) Always *Always* ***ALWAYS*** be sure you have good, verified, restore-tested backups of important data.

Comment: Wauw.. They can't give you another volume? What a crappy provider.. What about the ramdisc-stuff? I have no idea whether it will work or not, but it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

Giving the additional detail in your edit, I would say you need professional help to have even a slim chance to recover from this.

Some steps you could try (if possible with your provider)

1. Shut down the machine
2. Start the instance from a rescue system
3. `dd` your volume to another machine
4. Alternatively, ask your ISP if he can provide you an image file of the instance
5. Mount this image on another machine
6. Make a second volume for `ext4magic` and try to recover from the image file.

Yes, this is involved, hence the recommendation to get professional help.